# Android Studio Error:Class android.support.v4.hardware.display.DisplayManagerCompat has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing following exception when trying to build my android project using Android Studio

```
Error:Class android.support.v4.hardware.display.DisplayManagerCompat has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.
```

I tried different suggestion here on StackOverflow for example excluding the package like below but it still the same:

```
dependencies {
    dependencies {
        //compile project(':android-beacon-library')
        compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+@aar'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
        compile ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0') {
            exclude group: 'android.support', module: 'library'
        }
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
        compile('com.github.Comcast:FreeFlow:v-0.6') {
            exclude group: 'android.support', module: 'library'
        }
    }
}
```

Using gradlew.bat command i tried finding the duplicate entries but in output of the command it isn't there, pasted below is the output of `gradlew.bat :app:dependencies`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+ -> 2.3.3
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
\--- com.github.Comcast:FreeFlow:v-0.6
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0
          \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+ -> 2.3.3
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
\--- com.github.Comcast:FreeFlow:v-0.6
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0
          \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0

_debugTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+ -> 2.3.3
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
\--- com.github.Comcast:FreeFlow:v-0.6
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0
          \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0

_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+ -> 2.3.3
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
\--- com.github.Comcast:FreeFlow:v-0.6
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0
          \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0

androidJacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.1.201405082137

androidJacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.1.201405082137
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.1.201405082137
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.1.201405082137
     |    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.1.201405082137 (*)
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.1.201405082137

androidTestApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'androidTest' classes.
No dependencies

androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestProvided - Classpath for only compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'androidTest'.
No dependencies

apk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'main' classes.
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+ -> 2.3.3
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
\--- com.github.Comcast:FreeFlow:v-0.6
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0
          \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0

debugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'debug' classes.
No dependencies

debugCompile - Classpath for compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugProvided - Classpath for only compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'debug'.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
No dependencies

provided - Classpath for only compiling the main sources.
No dependencies

releaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'release' classes.
No dependencies

releaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseProvided - Classpath for only compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'release'.
No dependencies

wearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'main'.
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 9.674 secs
```

Comment: Run Gradle with --info or --debug options to find out why. This usually happens when you have a same file name in two different directories (i.e. in main source code and also somewhere in test source code / test IT source code etc). I also found that this can happen, if you have generated .class files for which you dont have .java files in the project but you created them on the fly (for ex: created during JIBX/XSL etc operations)

Answer (score 0):

Hi add this to your gradle file. It worked fine for me. Hope it will help you! :)

```
compile ('com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Add this code before dependencies :       configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support.v4', module: 'support-v4' } and let me know if it worked.